# Dual boot Ubuntu 16.06 aarch64 with CentOs 7.3 aarch64

Tags: ubuntu, centos, dual-boot

I have a running Ubuntu aarch64 box and would like to dual boot it with centOS aarch64. I currently don't have a bootable device like a cdrom or usb stick. What are my options for making this machine dual boot with CentOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure pxe on some other machine and use that to install the Centos7 on your current machine.